# LINQ: Help with groupby, doesn't seem to work like SQL :-) Only lets me return .Key and nothing else?

Tags: sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have the following linq query which is grouped

```
  var results = from c in C
     join h in h on c.Code equals
        h.Code
     join m in M on c.Code equals
        m.Code
          group c by c.Code into g
            select
              new 
              {
                 Group = g.Key,
                 Total = g.Count()
              }
```

works great, return 2 records, 1 item has a Total of 4 records and the other has a total of 2. Excellent its grouped!  but i am only returning the grouped field...

There is also field called tDate and on the H table and pCode on the M table.

now i tried changing my select to be like say but linqpad complains about the m and h variables because i presume they are not included in the group by... But this is where i am lost.. how do i return more fields on the group by. Of course both pCode and tDate are the same for every record within the group by... hence i should still end up with 2 records but with more columns.

```
            select
              new 
              {
                 Group = g.Key,
                 Total = g.Count(),
                 PCode = m.pCode,
                 TDate = h.tDate
              }
```

Any body give me a helping hand....

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "into", you remove all variables from scope that were declared before the `into`, and are left with only the variable declared after the `into`.

```
var results =
  from c in C 
  group c by c.Code into g 
  select new
  { 
    Group = g.Key, 
    Total = g.Count() 
  } into x
  from c2 in x
  join h in h on c2.Group equals h.Code 
  join m in M on c2.Group equals m.Code
  select new
  { 
    Group = x.Group, 
    Total = x.Total,
    PCode = m.pCode, 
    TDate = h.tDate
  };
```

Comment: Thanks David! Yep it works a treat! I would love to know which is the better way of doing this your method - works really well but have to include more joins after the intial group. Or Matoj where he has suggested using Max - which also seems to work and is less code but unsure the implications of using max... Why use max when there is not value(s) plural to get the max from ??

Comment: "Why use max when" : There is a plural established by grouping.  A group is a collection even if there's only one thing in it.

Comment: "Which is better":  My query has a subquery, his query does not.  My query groups on a targetted row set, his query groups on the result set.  From a performance standpoint, his query might be better, as joining first gives the optimizer choices on where to start.  From a correctness standpoint, I'd prefer my query, as grouping first will expose any faults introduced by joining on non-unique records (grouping after joining hides these faults).

Answer (score 2):

SQL would give you an error about the columns not being included as part of an aggregate function.  To include them, you have to include them in your group by, or join back onto the data to get them related to the grouped data.

Comment: Yes exactly, SQL would complain about the fields in the select part not being in the group by part but this is my issue, i don't understand how to transpose this in linq

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use a aggregate function to get the value. Have you tried `h.Max(y => y.tDate)` and `m.First(y => y.pCode)`? I think that might work but I'm not sure. Not all functions are aggregatefunctions.

Comment: Yes Max works! I like it! But .First doesn't.  Is this a trick? Good practice?  I suppose the rule behind it is that you can only return aggregate functions via a group if not specifically returned.. Hence doing a Max works :-)! Is this the best method to use? I have tried a few like First but doesn't work ... Max takes the max value but considering there is no more records is there a method to just print the value? Something like first - but first doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: `First` doesn't work since it is probably not an aggregate function I guess... I was just guessing with that one :). But in your case I guess you can use `Max` for both values? Otherwise here's an old link about how to write your own aggregate functions: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jomo_fisher/archive/2005/09/15/467804.aspx. I'm not sure it works though, but you could have it a try. `First` is not a trick, it's just not an aggregate function.

Answer (score 0):

> Of course both pCode and tDate are the same for every record within the group by.

If this is true, you can make them part of the key to get the results you want:

```
var results = 
      from c in C
      join h in H on c.Code equals h.Code
      join m in M on c.Code equals m.Code
      group c by new { cCode = c.Code, pCode = m.pCode, tDate = h.tDate } 
          into g
      select
          new
              {
                  Group = g.Key,
                  Total = g.Count()
              };
```

Now, for example, you can say

```
var firstcCode = results.First().Group.cCode;
var firstpCode = results.First().Group.pCode;
var firsttDate = results.First().Group.tDate;
```

If the statement I've quoted *isn't* true, then as suggested in other answers, just as in SQL, you need to invoke an aggregate function to say what to do with the (possibly many) `pCode` values for a given `cCode`.

Comment: Thanks Aajashm, it works but the key is like a collection then.. but thanks - it may come in useful later